Circuit capacitor debugging technique
I am by no means knowledgeable in EE, hence this very very basic question.
Not so long ago, I had nice PC Harman/Kardon speaker die on me. It hums what is probably a 60Hz loud tone. I have been told this typical issue is a capacitor blown up in the amplifier circuit. I intend to take a crack at fixing it just for fun (it is not so valuable).
Question: in order to test (with a multimeter or otherwise) a capacitor that's soldered onto a circuit, is it absolutely necessary to unsolder it off the circuit first, so it is isolated for testing?
Other than a capacitor, what else could be the issue for this typical amplifier issue?

If you can measure significant Vac ripple across a large cap in circuit with power on, then it is not doing its job to absorb ripple current.

Speaker model number / product page / anything?  A service manual with a schematic might be available online.

Yes, to measure the capacitor alone, it must be removed.
Otherwise you are measuring both the capacitor and the circuit that connects to the capacitor terminals.
However there are tens of reasons why your amplified speaker might output 60 Hz hum, and the first thing is to know if the problem is even in the amplified speaker or not. It could be a broken cable, oxidized or loose connector, or broken solder joint somewhere, which disconnects amplifier ground from PC ground.
To fix it, you need proper troubleshooting steps, before blindly believing what you are told that it's a blown up capacitor issue. They rarely blow up in circuits. They may defgrade but then the hum would start faintly and grow in amplitude over time. If the capacitor solder joint or ground s between devices suddenly becomes loose, hum would then appear immediately.

Question: in order to test (with a multimeter or otherwise) a capacitor that's soldered onto a circuit, is it absolutely necessary to unsolder it off the circuit first, so it is isolated for testing?
Yes, you have to remove the capacitor. Otherwise, the rest of the circuit will be loading the test measurement terminals as well as the capacitor. That circuitry can clamp the measurement waveform as well as present additional capacitance. The end result is a wrong measurement.

Other than a capacitor, what else could be the issue for this typical amplifier issue?
The low frequency hum typically indicates a linear power supply. The other sign of a linear supply is a relatively large and heavy transformer. It's usually the heaviest component by some margin, besides the speaker.
For a linear supply, a rectifier diode failing open circuit will produce hum. You should find the transformer output wires going to either two/four diodes or to a single 4-pin bridge rectifier component. Desolder each diode and test it with a multimeter's diode tester. Or desolder the single bridge rectifier then test it's internal four diodes through its four pins (an internet search will tell you how).
